# How to replaceData in DT rendered in R shiny using the datatable function

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have an `R` `shiny` app with a `DT` `datatable` that is rendered using the `datatable` function in order to set various options. I would like to use `dataTableProxy` and `replaceData` to update the data in the table, but all the examples I can find assume the `DT` is rendered directly from the data object, not using the `datatable` function. The reprex below shows what I would like to do, but `replaceData` doesn't work in this pattern. How do I do this? Thanks.

```
# based on 
# https://community.rstudio.com/t/reorder-data-table-with-seleceted-rows-first/4254

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("button1", "Randomize"),
    fluidRow(
        column(6,
               h4("Works"),
               DT::dataTableOutput('table1', width="90%")),
        column(6,
               h4("Doesn't Work"),
               DT::dataTableOutput('table2', width="90%"))
    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

        my <- reactiveValues(data = iris)

        output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(isolate(my$data))

        output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT::datatable(isolate(my$data),
                          options = list(lengthChange=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, searching=FALSE,
                                       columnDefs=list(list(className='dt-center', targets="_all")),
                                       stateSave=TRUE, info=FALSE),
                          class = "nowrap cell-border hover stripe",
                          rownames = FALSE,
                          editable = FALSE
            ) %>%
                DT::formatStyle('Sepal.Width', `text-align`="center")
        })

        observeEvent(input$button1, {

            # calculate new row order
            row_order <- sample(1:nrow(my$data))
            my$data <- my$data[row_order, ]

            proxy1 <- DT::dataTableProxy('table1')
            DT::replaceData(proxy1, my$data)
            proxy2 <- DT::dataTableProxy('table2')
            DT::replaceData(proxy2, my$data)

        })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you try to select more than one? It works in that case

Comment: Thanks, the problem is with the data refreshing. I've updated the reprex.

Comment: I would try `replaceData` with the option `rownames = FALSE`, that is `DT::replaceData(proxy2, my$data, rownames = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: Very strangely, removing `rownames = FALSE` made it all possible. I'm not exactly sure why, but probably rownames might be essential for replacing Data.

```
# based on 
# https://community.rstudio.com/t/reorder-data-table-with-seleceted-rows-first/4254

library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton("button1", "Randomize"),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           h4("Works"),
           DT::dataTableOutput('table1', width="90%")),
    column(6,
           h4("Doesn't Work"),
           DT::dataTableOutput('table2', width="90%"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  my <- reactiveValues(data = iris)

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(isolate(my$data))

  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(isolate(my$data),
                  options = list(lengthChange=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, searching=FALSE,
                                 columnDefs=list(list(className='dt-center', targets="_all")),
                                 stateSave=TRUE, info=FALSE),
                  class = "nowrap cell-border hover stripe",
                 # rownames = FALSE,
                  editable = FALSE
    ) %>%
      DT::formatStyle('Sepal.Width', `text-align`="center")
  })

  observeEvent(input$button1, {

    # calculate new row order
    row_order <- sample(1:nrow(my$data))
    my$data <- my$data[row_order, ]

    proxy1 <- DT::dataTableProxy('table1')
    DT::replaceData(proxy1, my$data)
    proxy2 <- DT::dataTableProxy('table2')
    DT::replaceData(proxy2, my$data)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the reprex to more clearly show my problem.

Comment: @SimonWoodward so you want the doesn't work part to work?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. The issue is I have extra formatting for my table, but this seems to prevent replaceData from working.

Comment: Awesome, good job! Although I really don't want the row names... unless I can customise them...

Comment: @SimonWoodward Note that you can pass `rownames=FALSE` to `replaceData` as well.

Comment: And how can I update options in the datatable?
DT::replaceData(proxy1, my$data) replaces the data but how can I do the same or the options.
For example I want to change language on the fly

Comment: To expand on the point @bobbel made, add `rownames=FALSE` to both `replaceData` and the call to `DT::datatable`, if you dont want the rownames.

Comment: I got this to work without the `isolate()` in the original tables. It did not work with it.