# Replace options in R Shiny datatable on the fly

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to change the language of a datatable on the fly

I have the following code

```
output$prr2 <- renderDataTable({  
prr()}, options = list(
autoWidth = TRUE,
columnDefs = list(list(width = '50', targets = c(1, 2) ) ),
language = list(url = if(getLanguage()=='gr') '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Greek.json' else  
  '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json' ))
```

getLanguage() returns the value of selected_language, prr() returns a data.frame.

I want to do something like this in order to change options of the table after selecting a different language in a dropdown selected_language

```
proxy = dataTableProxy('prr2')
observeEvent(input$selected_language,{ replace language option of datatable prr2})
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: Do you mean `language = list(url = if(getLanguage()=='gr') ......` does not work ?

Comment: It does work for the first time renderDataTable is called.
But I want to refresh it based on a selection. Every time the selection of the language changes, I would like the datatable to change its language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test since you don't provide a reproducible example. I would try

```
output$prr2 <- renderDataTable({  
  prr()
}, options = exprToFunction(list(
  autoWidth = TRUE,
  columnDefs = list(list(width = '50', targets = c(1, 2))),
  language = list(
    url = ifelse(getLanguage()=='gr', 
                 '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Greek.json', 
                 '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json')
  )
)))
```

---

## EDIT

```
output$prr2 <- renderDataTable({  
  datatable(
    prr(),
    options = exprToFunction(list(
      autoWidth = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '50', targets = c(1, 2))),
      language = list(
        url = ifelse(getLanguage()=='gr', 
                     '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Greek.json', 
                     '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json')
      )
    )
    )
  )
})
```

---

## EDIT 2

Full app which works:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("language", "Language", choices = c("gr", "en")),
  DTOutput("prr2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$prr2 <- renderDT({  
    datatable(
      iris,
      options = exprToFunction(list(
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(width = '50', targets = c(1, 2))),
        language = list(
          url = ifelse(input$language=='gr', 
                       '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Greek.json', 
                       '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/English.json')
        )
      ))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If the only change is exprToFunction, it seems that this solution does not work for me.
When I change the value of the doropdown with id selected_language nothing happens to the translation of the datatable
I should add that getLanguage() returns the value of selected_language

Comment: I have copy pasted your code and it produces no errors but does not work.
prr() returns a data.frame

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879672/how-to-replacedata-in-dt-rendered-in-r-shiny-using-the-datatable-function/59715287#59715287

https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/168

Here are some related examples but the code there replaces the data and not the options

Comment: @vagelis For me it works. Perhaps you don't use the good `renderDataTable`. Use `renderDT` or `DT::renderDataTable`.

Comment: Yes this works. I changed the getLanguage() with input$selected_language and it works(I don't understand why). Thanks!
Additionally could you explain the exprToFunction why it works?